# OBIEE :Creating Dynamic Dashboard objects based on Input in Dashboard Prompt

Tags: obiee

Based on the input given in my dashboard prompt,the number of dashboard objects that should be displayed on my dashboard in OBIEE will be varying.
How should I handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that using section conditions on your dashboard.

- First make your dashboard prompts to populate presentation variables
- Use those presentation variables to filter auxiliary analysis so they return rows when your section needs to be shown.
- Enable the conditions on your sections to use these aux analysis and set the condition to evaluate to true when the rowcount of the analysis is > 0

Another path would be to use javascript to manipulate the DOM. Just add some custom CSS classes to the sections (using section format options) and add a bit of JS that look for these classes and depending your logic remove or hide them.

Hope that helps!